# Identifying only numeric values from a column in a Data Frame- Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, automation

I Want a Separate column which returns "Yes" if the column **"ID**" contains all numeric values and 'No' if it contains alphabets or alphanumeric values.

```
ID      Result
3965      Yes
wyq8      No
RO_123    No
CMD_      No
2976      Yes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Series.str.isnumeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html) here.

```
df['Result'] = np.where(df['ID'].str.isnumeric(), 'YES', 'NO')

       ID Result
0    3965    YES
1    wyq8     NO
2  RO_123     NO
3    CMD_     NO
4    2976    YES
```

There's a caveat with using `isnumeric` it doesn't identify `float` numbers.

```py
test = pd.Series(["9.0", "9"])
test.str.isnumeric()

0    False
1     True
dtype: bool
```

If you strictly mark `YES` for `int` then use `isnumeric` else you can use [`pd.Series.str.fullmatch`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#testing-for-strings-that-match-or-contain-a-pattern)(available from version 1.1.0) here.

```
df['Result'] = np.where(df['ID'].str.fullmatch(r"\d+|\d+\.\d+", 'YES', 'NO')
```

For version <1.1.0 you use [`re.fullmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.fullmatch)

```
numeric_pat = re.compile(r"\d+|\d+\.\d+")
def numeric(val):
    match = numeric_pat.fullmatch(val)
    if match: return 'YES'
    else: return 'NO'

df['Result'] = df['ID'].apply(numeric)
```

Or we can use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with boolean masking using [`pd.Series.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html)

```
m = pd.to_numeric(df['ID'], errors='coerce').isna()
df['Result'] = np.where(m, 'NO', 'YES')
```

With `errors` parameter set to `'coerce'` values which cannot be turned into numeic value will set to `Nan`.

```
test = pd.Series(['3965', 'wyq8', 'RO_123', 'CMD_', '2976'])
pd.to_numeric(test)

0    3965.0
1       NaN
2       NaN
3       NaN
4    2976.0
Name: ID, dtype: float64
```

Or you can build a custom function

```
def numeric(val):
    try:
        float(val)     # Using just `float` would suffice as int can be 
        return 'YES'   # converted to `float` so both `int`
                       # and `float` wouldnot raise any error
    except ValueError:
        return 'NO'

df['Result'] = df['ID'].apply(numeric)
```

*Note*: `float` handles scientic notation too, `float("1e6")` -> `1000000.0`.

```
test = pd.Series(['1e6', '1', 'a 10', '1E6'])
test.apply(numeric)

0    YES
1    YES
2     NO
3    YES
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

Check if `ID` contains `non-digits`and reverse the Boolean selection using `~`. Using `np.where`, allocate option

```
df['Result']=np.where(~df.ID.str.contains('(\D+)'),'Yes','N0')

     ID Result
0    3965    Yes
1    wyq8     N0
2  RO_123     N0
3    CMD_     N0
4    2976    Yes
```

As noted by @Cameron Riddell. You could also skip inverting the boolean and do the following;

```
df['Result']=np.where(df.ID.str.contains('(\D+)'),'No','Yes')
```

Comment: Instead of inverting the boolean array, why not just make `"No"` the `True` value and `"Yes"` the `False` value? `np.where(df.ID.str.contains('(\D+)'),'No','Yes')`

Comment: @Cameron Riddell we actually could. My philosophy is to make answer as retraceable as possible for the OP if they choose to run break it down. Good point though.

Comment: This would fail when there's a string `'123 SO'`, using `re.fullmatch` would counter that example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.isnumeric()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html?highlight=isnumeric#pandas.Series.str.isnumeric) method:

```
df3["Result"] = df3["ID"].str.isnumeric().apply(lambda x: "No" if x == False else "Yes")
```

**[UPDATE]:** This method works only with integers numbers, please view the @Ch3steR answer for other cases.